# 'SageMaker' object has no attribute 'update_feature_group'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to call udpate_feature_group() function from sagemaker boto3 API.

```
client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
response = client.update_feature_group(FeatureGroupName=featureGroupName,FeatureAdditions=featureAdditions)
```

however I'm getting below error

```
'SageMaker' object has no attribute 'update_feature_group'
```

I verified the boto3 version being used in lambda, it is 1.24.62
which has update_feature_group() function as well
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.24.62/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.update_feature_group

then it should not complaint? any idea why I am getting that error?

Comment: Have you tested the behviour with the latest version (1.24.69)? Is the behaviour the same?